# Minrole topology - Web Front End server with Distributed Cache services

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, distributedcache, minrole, wfe

If configuring WFE server with `Distributed Cache`, during installation would this server have to be installed as a custom role?

Or the `Distributed Cache` service can be added later after installing a WFE server role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the installation process you have to select the "Front-end with Distributed Cache" role and complete the configuration. Post configuration, you can apply changes to your DC if any( changing max memory, service account etc).

You should be at least on November 2017 CU level as this role introduced in that cu.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910(v=office.16).aspx

Comment: November 2016 introduced it. But everyone should be on the latest PU available.

Comment: i agree, i mean  at least November cu.

Answer (score 1):

No, just install it as DC+FE. You can add further DC+FEs later.